# Spotify API POST Request - Add Tracks to Playlist: Items Not Added In Order

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, spotify

This is my fetch request code: (which works fine BUT the songs are not added in the order that they are in in the trackIdArr state).

```
// Add tracks to playlist
    await fetch(
      `https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/${playlistId}/tracks`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ uris: trackIdArr }),
      }
    );
```

Spotify API doc reads:
If [position query is] omitted, the items will be appended to the playlist. Items are added in the order they are listed in the query string or request body.

How can I fix this? I have tried using for of loop, axios, adding a position parameter but it seems as though since it is an async await request, the items would not be added in order. So, why does spotify claim that it would? Am I doing something wrong? Thank you!